# Automatically replace files in destination when dropping zip into batch

Tags: batch, overwrite, unzip

I'm using the following code in a batch to unzip files to a specific destination. What can I add in order to have the extracted files automatically overwrite the existing files?

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "C:\Temp\" "c:\FolderName\batch.zip"
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
```

Comment: To make your code more readable, could you please put it in a code block? (I.e. indent with 4 spaces)

Comment: Use constants defined [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee176633(v=technet.10)) `>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip, &H14)`